# How to prevent 2.6 rounding off to 3 in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am working on a program and the only problem i am facing is that a decimal like 2.6 is being rounded off to 3 or any other number like 1.7 is being rounded off to 2.
How can I make it to round 1.6 off to just 1?

Any help will really be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

That feature is called "Truncate".  There's a [`Math.truncate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d101hyf.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) function.  From the docs:

```
Dim decimalNumber As Decimal

decimalNumber = 32.7865d
' Displays 32      
Console.WriteLine(Math.Truncate(decimalNumber))

decimalNumber = -32.9012d
' Displays -32
Console.WriteLine(Math.Truncate(decimalNumber))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [**Math.Floor Method (Double)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) as of from .NET Framework 2.0

Examples:

```
Floor(2.10) = 2
Floor(2.00) = 2
Floor(1.90) = 1
Floor(1.80) = 1
Floor(1.70) = 1
Floor(1.60) = 1
Floor(1.50) = 1
Floor(1.40) = 1
Floor(1.30) = 1
Floor(1.20) = 1
Floor(1.10) = 1
Floor(1.00) = 1
```

Comment: this is cool but i want 1.00 to be 1.00 only. I just need the others to be floored down. is there a way to do that ?

Comment: @kunalgrover The above example is from .NET framework 1.1.  But in .NET framework 2.0 it looks good like `Floor(1.00) = 1`  check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb(v=vs.80).aspx also update this in answer.